# Python - How to convert escaped sequence to string literals

Tags: python, string, encoding, escaping

Somewhat new to python, to be honest not very familiar with encoding in Python

Suppose while parsing text/html inputs, I end up with a path that look like following

```
line = \\dfslocation\prj\gct\asw\sw_archive
```

However in the earlier part of processing, it seems like the escaped sequence '\a' and \'t' is already no longer stored as literal.

```
literal_line = "%r"%(line)
print literal_line   

\\dfslocation\prj\gct\x07sw\\sw_archive
```

My best guess is it happened when I tried to convert email into text

```
for part in self.msg.walk():
  if part.get_content_type().startswith('text/plain'):
    plain_text_part = part.get_payload(decode=False)
    received_text += '\n'
    received_text += plain_text_part

received_text = received_text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Later on I want to use this as a network path, which would require this to be in its literal form - ie \a, not \x07 (ASCII Bel character)

The brute force way I can think of, would be searching all escaped sequence https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html, and replacing them with corresponding string literals.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try storing line variable content as raw instead of ASCII.

If you store as it is, the `\a` will get converted to `x07`.

```
>>> line = "\\dfslocation\prj\gct\asw\sw_archive"
>>> line
'\\dfslocation\\prj\\gct\x07sw\\sw_archive'
```

However, if you store as raw, using `r'<your_ascii_text>'` format, it will not convert to special characters.

```
>>> line  = r'\\dfslocation\prj\gct\asw\sw_archive'
>>> print line
\\dfslocation\prj\gct\asw\sw_archive
>>>
```

Raw strings treat `\a` as `\a`, making them well adapted for windows filenames and regular expressions.